# Split string at delimiter '\' in python

Tags: python-2.7, split

I have a quick question. 
I am trying to split a string S : `'greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings'` at `'\'` using:

```
     S.split('\')
```

I expect output list :

```
 ['greenland.gdb', 'topology_check', 't_buildings'].
```

Instead it returns error : `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`. What is with character '\' in python. With any other character it works fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
 S.split('\\')
```

You may also need to string_escape:

```
In [10]: s = 'greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings'

In [11]: s.split("\\")
Out[11]: ['greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings']

In [12]: s.encode("string_escape").split("\\")
Out[12]: ['greenland.gdb', 'topology_check', 't_buildings']
```

`\t` would be interpreted as a tab character unless you were using a raw string:

```
In [18]: s = 'greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings'

In [19]: print(s)
greenland.gdb   opology_check   _buildings

In [20]: s = r'greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings'

In [21]: print(s)
greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings
```

[Escape characters](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html)

Comment: it doesnot work . i have already tried. '\\' is a different character in itself.

Comment: @Larry, no it h is not a different characer,   if you want a literal `\\` then you need to escape it

Comment: that makes sense. it works with methods encode and split in cascade . Thanks !

Comment: This doesn't work anymore for python3 (LookupError: unknown encoding: string_escape). Any idea?

Comment: I just found it should be **unicode_escape** in python3, but it is not suitable for string. only works for byte-like data

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a raw string first, 'r' or 'R' as follows:

```
In [01]: s = r'greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings'
```

Then split while remembering to escape the backslash

```
In [02]:  s.split('\\')

Out [02]: ['greenland.gdb', 'topology_check', 't_buildings']
```

Quoting from [re — Regular expression operations (Python documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html)

> `\` Either escapes special characters (permitting you to match
>   characters like '*', '?', and so forth), or signals a special
>   sequence; special sequences are discussed below.
>
> If you’re not using a raw string to express the pattern, remember that
>   Python also uses the backslash as an escape sequence in string
>   literals; if the escape sequence isn’t recognized by Python’s parser,
>   the backslash and subsequent character are included in the resulting
>   string. However, if Python would recognize the resulting sequence, the
>   backslash should be repeated twice. This is complicated and hard to
>   understand, so it’s highly recommended that you use raw strings for
>   all but the simplest expressions.

Comment: Awesome! This address the issue mentioned by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484624/split-string-at-delimiter-in-python#comment102754002_37484670) with Python3

Answer (score 3):

Backslash \ is a special character , I dont like magic too but ,
in this  case (and for both python 2.7 and python 3 ):

```
>>> s = 'greenland.gdb\topology_check\t_buildings'
>>> s.split()
```

will give the desired output :

```
['greenland.gdb', 'opology_check', '_buildings']
```

Answer (score -1):

s = 'greenland.gdb**\t**opology_check**\t**_buildings'
python is consider this \t has the escape sequence .
\t - Indicates the whitespace in python.

for the above case we won't specify any separater .space considered as default separater.
input- print (s.split())
output- ['greenland.gdb', 'opology_check', '_buildings']

If I am wrong correct me .